# My app works fine in debug version and only crash in release version when using the following method of AFNewtworking 3.0

Tags: ios, swift, crash, afnetworking-3

```
// This line crashes in release version (TestFlight)
// a method called from AFNetworking 3, I added it using CocoaPods. 

let dataTask:NSURLSessionDataTask =
self.afUrlSessionManager!.dataTaskWithRequest(request) { (response, responseObject, error) in

        if( error != nil){
                        loginFailure(error,nil)

                    }else{
        // parse responseObject json
        let loginData:NSMutableDictionary =  responseObject as! NSMutableDictionary
                    }
            }
dataTask.resume()
```

The crash report sent by Apple review team:

```
Incident Identifier: D2CE605A-2EC7-4BCE-B8B7-07BC5F93E56D
CrashReporter Key:   d66ba2277da7577ba138220c9e93f0d613cebb50
Hardware Model:      xxx
Process:             AfaqyGPS [366]
Path:                /private/var/containers/Bundle/Application/2A6F7DAC-41A2-42A4-8DE1-4C8100F5F58B/AfaqyGPS.app/AfaqyGPS

        Identifier:          AF-GP
        Version:             5.0 (1.0)
        Code Type:           ARM-64 (Native)
        Role:                Foreground
        Parent Process:      launchd [1]
        Coalition:           AF-GP [447]


        Date/Time:           2016-10-18 21:29:29.6894 -0700
        Launch Time:         2016-10-18 21:29:21.1932 -0700
        OS Version:          iPhone OS 10.0.2 (14A456)
        Report Version:      104

        Exception Type:  EXC_CRASH (SIGABRT)
        Exception Codes: 0x0000000000000000, 0x0000000000000000
        Exception Note:  EXC_CORPSE_NOTIFY
        Triggered by Thread:  0

        Application Specific Information:
        abort() called

        Filtered syslog:
        None found

        Thread 0 name:  Dispatch queue: com.apple.main-thread
        Thread 0 Crashed:
        0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x0000000188d96014 0x188d77000 + 126996
        1   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x0000000188e5d460 0x188e58000 + 21600
        2   libsystem_c.dylib               0x0000000188d0a3f4 0x188ca7000 + 406516
        3   libswiftCore.dylib              0x0000000100980100 swift_deletedMethodError (__hidden#8337_:113)
        4   libswiftCore.dylib              0x0000000100965bc0 swift::swift_dynamicCastFailure(swift::Metadata const*, swift::Metadata const*, char const*) (__hidden#7547_:409)
        5   libswiftCore.dylib              0x0000000100965c50 swift_dynamicCastClass (__hidden#7547_:501)
        6   libswiftCore.dylib              0x000000010098ee04 swift_dynamicCastObjCClassUnconditional (__hidden#9867_:1003)
        7   AfaqyGPS                        0x00000001001518d4 static Services.(login(String, password : String, loginSuccess : () -> (), loginFailure : (NSError?, NSString?) -> ()) -> ()).(closure #1) (Services.swift:801)
        8   AFNetworking                    0x0000000100661594 __72-[AFURLSessionManagerTaskDelegate URLSession:task:didCompleteWithError:]_block_invoke_2.150 (AFURLSessionManager.m:308)
        9   libdispatch.dylib               0x0000000188c51200 0x188c50000 + 4608
        10  libdispatch.dylib               0x0000000188c511c0 0x188c50000 + 4544
        11  libdispatch.dylib               0x0000000188c55b30 0x188c50000 + 23344
        12  CoreFoundation                  0x0000000189d75f2c 0x189c99000 + 905004
        13  CoreFoundation                  0x0000000189d73b18 0x189c99000 + 895768
        14  CoreFoundation                  0x0000000189ca2048 0x189c99000 + 36936
        15  GraphicsServices                0x000000018b725198 0x18b719000 + 49560
        16  UIKit                           0x000000018fc75628 0x18fbfa000 + 505384
        17  UIKit                           0x000000018fc70360 0x18fbfa000 + 484192
        18  AfaqyGPS                        0x000000010011c07c main (AppDelegate.swift:14)
        19  libdyld.dylib                   0x0000000188c845b8 0x188c80000 + 17848

        Thread 1:
        0   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x0000000188e58db0 0x188e58000 + 3504

        Thread 2:
        0   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x0000000188e58db0 0x188e58000 + 3504

        Thread 3 name:  com.apple.uikit.eventfetch-thread
        Thread 3:
        0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x0000000188d7816c 0x188d77000 + 4460
        1   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x0000000188d77fdc 0x188d77000 + 4060
        2   CoreFoundation                  0x0000000189d75cec 0x189c99000 + 904428
        3   CoreFoundation                  0x0000000189d73908 0x189c99000 + 895240
        4   CoreFoundation                  0x0000000189ca2048 0x189c99000 + 36936
        5   Foundation                      0x000000018a7b0b1c 0x18a7a4000 + 51996
        6   Foundation                      0x000000018a7d160c 0x18a7a4000 + 185868
        7   UIKit                           0x00000001905eac7c 0x18fbfa000 + 10423420
        8   Foundation                      0x000000018a8ae50c 0x18a7a4000 + 1090828
        9   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x0000000188e5b860 0x188e58000 + 14432
        10  libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x0000000188e5b770 0x188e58000 + 14192
        11  libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x0000000188e58dbc 0x188e58000 + 3516

        Thread 4:
        0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x0000000188d96a88 0x188d77000 + 129672
        1   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x0000000188e5936c 0x188e58000 + 4972
        2   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x0000000188e58db4 0x188e58000 + 3508

        Thread 5 name:  com.apple.NSURLConnectionLoader
        Thread 5:
        0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x0000000188d7816c 0x188d77000 + 4460
        1   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x0000000188d77fdc 0x188d77000 + 4060
        2   CoreFoundation                  0x0000000189d75cec 0x189c99000 + 904428
        3   CoreFoundation                  0x0000000189d73908 0x189c99000 + 895240
        4   CoreFoundation                  0x0000000189ca2048 0x189c99000 + 36936
        5   CFNetwork                       0x000000018a48fcec 0x18a3c3000 + 838892
        6   Foundation                      0x000000018a8ae50c 0x18a7a4000 + 1090828
        7   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x0000000188e5b860 0x188e58000 + 14432
        8   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x0000000188e5b770 0x188e58000 + 14192
        9   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x0000000188e58dbc 0x188e58000 + 3516

        Thread 6:
        0   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x0000000188e58db0 0x188e58000 + 3504

        Thread 0 crashed with ARM Thread State (64-bit):
            x0: 0x0000000000000000   x1: 0x0000000000000000   x2: 0x0000000000000000   x3: 0x00000001702c34a6
            x4: 0x0000000000000014   x5: 0x0000000000000020   x6: 0x0000000000000000   x7: 0x0000000000000cf0
            x8: 0x0000000008000000   x9: 0x0000000004000000  x10: 0x0000000000003db5  x11: 0x00000001b0989bcb
           x12: 0x00000001b0989bcb  x13: 0x0000000000000018  x14: 0x0000000000000001  x15: 0x0000000000000881
           x16: 0x0000000000000148  x17: 0x0000000000000000  x18: 0x0000000000000000  x19: 0x0000000000000006
           x20: 0x00000001ae3eec40  x21: 0x00000001ae3f40d8  x22: 0x000000016fd02a58  x23: 0x000000016fd02a40
           x24: 0x000000010013cae8  x25: 0x0000000170472bc0  x26: 0xffffffffffffffff  x27: 0x0000000170469bc0
           x28: 0x000000010013cab4   fp: 0x000000016fd02990   lr: 0x0000000188e5d460
            sp: 0x000000016fd02970   pc: 0x0000000188d96014 cpsr: 0x00000000
```

Comment: What is line 801 of Services.swift?

Comment: I mentioned it in the question.

Comment: So you have an empty closure?  Why are you fetching data if you aren't doing anything with it? Since you have a failure in a forced downcast (`as!`) and the code shown doesn't include one, I presume you aren't showing the actual code. Please show it

Comment: I have code in the closure but not mentioned, because the crash in this line and not reach the code in closure so no need for the code in the closure.

Comment: The crash is in that closure. Please show it

Comment: So , it seems that `responseObject` is *not* an `NSMutableDictionary`. I would expect it to be an `NSDictionary` rather than a mutable dictionary, but any time you forced downcast you have a potential for a crash, so you should code more defensively.

Comment: @ Paulw11  It works fine in debug mode my questio that crash only happens in Testflight release build.

Comment: To be honest, it doesn't matter why. Your code is not robust. Fix the forced downcast

Comment: The crash is *clearly* in the closure that was invoked by AFNetworking. Further the crash is a failure to perform a dynamic cast. Since you have a forced downcast to NSMutableArray in the closure this is almost certainly where your crash is.

Answer (score 0):

Finally I fixed the issue, I was using the following method to encode parameters json object that appended to the URL and that makes the application to crash only in release version. I removed it and used instead `data.stringByAddingPercentEncodingWithAllowedCharacters(NSCharacterSet.URLHostAllowedCharacterSet())`; it works fine and the application was approved.

```
+(id)getJSONDictObjFromString:(NSString *)jsonString{
    NSError * err;
    if ([jsonString isKindOfClass:[NSDictionary class]]) {

        return jsonString;
    }

    NSData *data =[jsonString dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
    NSDictionary * response;
    if(data!=nil){
        response = (NSDictionary *)[NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:data options:NSJSONReadingMutableContainers error:&err];
    }
    return response;
}
```